# How do I add a new commit with a commit date of two hours ago in git?

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project and for multiple reasons, I need a commit of code that I have just completed to have the date of two hours ago.  Is there a way to do this?  I am not very familiar with git.  Usually, I would type in "git commit -m 'message'".  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware that there are two dates associated with a commit (the author date and the commit date) and what the difference is between them? Do you know which of these dates you're interested in changing?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to set is the author date, use `--date` as suggested above.  If you want to set the committer date then:

```
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="<some date>" git commit -m 'message'
```